# How to fix implicit declaration of function during compilation of android kernel

Tags: android, c, linux

I have imported qcacld-3.0 driver from CAF which is default WLAN driver for my device. However, I am getting this [error](https://hastebin.com/yagiyiyico.coffeescript) which I can't get how to fix. It seems perfectly declared to me. I am still a beginner at C, so might be missing something. Kindy, explain me how to fix this error and why that particular fix is chosen. Here is my kernel [source](https://github.com/theimpulson/kami_kernel_nokia_sdm660).

Comment: @LuisColorado should have also suggested not using links to post errors, since links can expire. By the way, your link expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding a declaration to the header file.

Comment: Don't answer your own questions.  Or explain the way to solve it (why adding a declaration solves the problem) for this question to be useful to others.